# If a function (say g(x)) is positive at any point, does it mean the g(x)+g(-x) should return a expression that is also positive at any point?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

My original question was to prove that the function $f(x) = x^3 - 3x^2 + 6x - 100$ is increasing at any real number $R$ and so I solved for the derivative $f'(x)$ which is $3x^2-6x+6$.

Although there are many ways the prove $f'(x)$ is a positive number at any point given that $f(x)$ does not decrease, What I tried to do is insert the positive and negative of the same number (say $R$) as a domain to $f'(x)$ and summed the both such that the expression is $f'(R) + f'(-R)$. When I tried it:

$$
f'(R)+f'(-R)=(3R^2−6R+6) + (3(-R)^2−6(-R)+6
$$
$$
=3R^2−6R+6 + 3R^2+6R+6$$
$$
=6R^2+12
$$
$$
6(R^2+2)$$
And it is easy to see that the result $6(R^2+2)$ should also be positive at any point. From what I said, I assume that it should prove that $f'(x)$ gives a positive number at any point which in return proves that $f(x)$ will always increase at any point.

so my assumption is that for any real number R and function g(x), if g(R) + g(-R) gives an expression that is positive at any point, then g(x) is a function that only returns a positive value. Is my assumption correct or does it only work for certain functions that are given to be positive at any point?

Comment: Consider $f(x) = 1-x, f(R)+f(-R) = 2$ for all $R$ but the function is negative for all $R> 1.$  For the problem above, $f'(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial, so it is continuous.  If it is ever negative, it must pass through zero.  Plugging into the quadratic formula show it has no real zeros, hence it is either always positive or always negative.

Comment: ... or just $3x^2-6x+6=3(x-1)^2+3\ge 3$. But the OP already stated that there are other (and correct) ways to prove $f'>0$.

Comment: @DougM Thanks for that example and it seems I didn't think enough. Maybe I will try to work with my assumption with some more examples.

Comment: And also @HagenvonEitzen proved the answer in the supposed way and correct way. I know it but I was a bit bored so yes.